# Dependence of phase factor when interchanging two identical particles on spin

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, identical-particles

In Weinberg's textbook on QFT (page 171), he discussed the phase $\alpha_n$ picked up when interchanging two identical particles. Generally, the phase may depend on the spin of two particles interchanged,
$$
\Psi_{\mathbf{p}_1 \sigma_1 n \mathbf{p}_2 \sigma_2 n} = \alpha_n(\sigma_1,\sigma_2) \Psi_{\mathbf{p}_2 \sigma_2 n \mathbf{p}_1 \sigma_1 n},
$$
where $p_i$ and $\sigma_i$ are momentums and spin $z$-components of the $i$-th particle.

He says

> The phase $\alpha_n$, cannot have any non-trivial dependence on the spins of the two particles that are interchanged, because then these spin-dependent phase factors would
> have to furnish a representation of the rotation group, and there are no non-trivial representations of the three-dimensional rotation group that are one-dimensional — that is, by phase factors.

I can not understand why a spin-dependent phase $\alpha_n(\sigma_1,\sigma_2)$ will generate a non-trivial one-dimensional representation of the three-dimensional rotation group.

For simplicity, we assume two particles are at rest ($\mathbf{p}_1 = \mathbf{p}_2 = \mathbf{0}$). Under a rotation $\mathcal{R}$, we have
$$
U(\mathcal{R})\Psi_{\mathbf{0} \sigma_1 n \mathbf{0} \sigma_2 n} = \alpha_n(\sigma_1,\sigma_2) U(\mathcal{R}) \Psi_{\mathbf{0} \sigma_2 n \mathbf{0} \sigma_1 n}.
$$

Using equation 3.1.1 on page 108, we have
$$
D_{\sigma_1^{\prime}\sigma_1}(\mathcal{R}) D_{\sigma_2^{\prime}\sigma_2}(\mathcal{R}) \Psi_{\sigma_1^{\prime} \sigma_2^{\prime}} = \alpha_n(\sigma_1,\sigma_2) D_{\sigma_2^{\prime}\sigma_2}(\mathcal{R}) D_{\sigma_1^{\prime}\sigma_1}(\mathcal{R}) \Psi_{\sigma_2^{\prime} \sigma_1^{\prime}}.
$$
Here we omit the label of momentum and particle species for simplicity.

Using $\Psi_{\sigma_1^{\prime} \sigma_2^{\prime}} = \alpha_n(\sigma_1^{\prime},\sigma_2^{\prime}) \Psi_{\sigma_2^{\prime} \sigma_1^{\prime}}$, we get
$$
\alpha_n(\sigma_1^{\prime},\sigma_2^{\prime})  D_{\sigma_1^{\prime}\sigma_1}(\mathcal{R}) D_{\sigma_2^{\prime}\sigma_2}(\mathcal{R}) \Psi_{\sigma_2^{\prime} \sigma_1^{\prime}} = \alpha_n(\sigma_1,\sigma_2) D_{\sigma_2^{\prime}\sigma_2}(\mathcal{R}) D_{\sigma_1^{\prime}\sigma_1}(\mathcal{R}) \Psi_{\sigma_2^{\prime} \sigma_1^{\prime}}
$$
and so
$$
\alpha_n(\sigma_1^{\prime},\sigma_2^{\prime})  D_{\sigma_1^{\prime}\sigma_1}(\mathcal{R}) D_{\sigma_2^{\prime}\sigma_2}(\mathcal{R})  = \alpha_n(\sigma_1,\sigma_2) D_{\sigma_2^{\prime}\sigma_2}(\mathcal{R}) D_{\sigma_1^{\prime}\sigma_1}(\mathcal{R}).
$$

I can not proceed further. But I still can not see that $\alpha_n(\sigma_1,\sigma_2)$ furnish a representation of the rotation group. And it seems that we can conclude that $\alpha_n(\sigma_1,\sigma_2) = \alpha_n(\sigma_1^{\prime},\sigma_2^{\prime})$ directly.

Any help is appreciated.